# Recursion function in R

Tags: r, recursion

Here is the code, that calculate the binomial coefficient:

```
binomial_coef <- function(n,r){
    if (n == r | r == 0){
        return(1)
    }
    else{
        result <- binomial_coef(n-1,r-1) + binomial_coef(n-1,r)
        return(result)
    }
}
```

Can you please explain how this code works? How can it calculate, when the function(binomial_coef) isn't define(I mean, there is no formula inside the code)

Thanks

Comment: There are some tutorials out there if you google for `recursive function r`, e.g. this one: http://www.programiz.com/r-programming/recursion

Comment: To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion. Jokes aside, take this example: `binomial_coef(2, 1)`. Get a pen and paper, and figure out what is happening at each step. You'll understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The function(binomial_coef) is indeed defined. This is another way of solving nCr.

nCr= n-1Cr-1 + n-1Cr

So the required nCr gets calculated according to this formula recursively.